# How to trigger a Gitlab-CI pipeline using Gitlab API for latest tag?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I am reading [Gitlab-CI API trigger documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).

I understand that with:

```sh
curl -X POST \
     -F token=<token> \
     -F ref=master \
     https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/142/trigger/pipeline
```

I can trigger the latest pipeline for `master`.

How can I trigger the latest pipeline for the latest tag with CURL and the Gitlab-CI API?